# PyTorch: Why does the inference of my conditional. diffusion model (Palette) always lead to bad predictions?

Tags: pytorch, output, inference, pytorch-lightning

I am trying to implement [Palette](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.05826.pdf), which is a conditional diffusion model, and I am having some trouble with the inference algorithm. Currently, I am just trying to use it to model a very simple dataset of all the same input images that are just scaled down versions of the output.

I have tried following:

1. The inference algorithm exactly as it is outlined in the paper on page 11. However, this always leads to a completely black output with a little bit of noise (some colored pixels, not everywhere). When printing the tensors, I see that the values diverge to very positive or very negative values. So, I feel like something is wrong there.
2. The inference algorithm as implemented in [this repository that implements Palette](https://github.com/Janspiry/Palette-Image-to-Image-Diffusion-Models/blob/main/models/network.py). But, this always leads to first going black for the first half of the iterations and then suddenly becoming a very noisy weird version of the output.

The training algorithm works fine. The loss decreases. So, the noise must be predicted somewhat correctly, but I feel like the inference algorithm is not correct. I do not understand why I get these weird output inference iterations...

Has anyone had any experience with implementing diffusion models that can give some pointers on the inference algorithm?

Btw, I am using PyTorch Lightning if that is relevant.

I tried implementing the mentioned inference algorithms. They gave very odd outputs. I expected the noise to be gradually removed as should happen in a diffusion model.